# Sencha stores as list data source

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm having a hard time trying to resolve the following thing. I've a store

```
Ext.define('aBMin.store.Email', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
requires : ['aBMin.model.Email'],
config : {
    autoLoad : true,
    model : 'aBMin.model.Email',
    remoteFilter : true,
    proxy : {
        type : 'direct',
        extraParams : {
            filter : 'unassigned'
        },
        directFn : ClientemailTable.getListMobile,
        config : {
            paramsAsHash : true,
            reader : {
                type : 'json'
                ,rootProperty : 'result'
                ,successProperty: 'success'
                ,totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

and the following json is being loaded to it:

```
[{"totalCount":8,"result":[],"tid":10,"method":"getListMobile","action":"ClientemailTable","type":"rpc"}]
```

Everything is being loaded properly except the 'totalCount' property to the store. When I'm trying to retrieve in in the Chrome's console, it prints 'null'.

**NOTE:** the 'result' property is loaded properly so in this case I'm presenting it as an empty array.

```
Ext.getStore('Email').getTotalCount()
> null
```

I use sencha touch 2.0. any ideas how to bing it?

Comment: Can you remove ` ,totalProperty: 'totalCount'` from reader and see it it works ?

Comment: When I did that: Ext.getStore('Email').getProxy().getReader().getTotalProperty() gave
"total" but Ext.getStore('Email').getTotalCount() still gives null.

Comment: See your code again.:)

Comment: If U've ment 'Ticket' in the store code I've change it but it was a typo in this post, the code is ok. Or have You ment something else? / Updated the code

Comment: 4th Line - 
config : {
            paramsAsHash : true,
            reader : {
                type : 'json'
                ,rootProperty : 'result'
                ,successProperty: 'success'
                ,totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            }
        }

Comment: Do U mean the 'rootProperty'? I'm not sure what do You want to point out

Comment: No, I meant totalProperty.

Comment: I've removed it from the code - it gave the result as I've mented above. The same implementation is in here: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/05/sencha-touch-list-load-more.html. Can u see some more mistakes within the code?

Comment: rootProperty should have all the json objects within like - 
{"ROOT":[{"TestCaseName":"SearchHotel","TotalCount":"18"},{"TestCaseName":"android.location","TotalCount":"16"}]}

Comment: Thanx for the complete answer, if You'll place above comment as an answer than I'll check it as my enclosing answer for that question. Thanx once again :).